# Helps with Flask pagination

Tags: python, flask, pagination

I have a block of looping jinja on a page, and I want to paginate it. I'm following [this tutorial](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-paginate/), but it's not working. I get "ImportError: No module named flask_paginate."

Here's the relevant bit of the .py code:

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_paginate import Pagination, get_page_parameter

mod = Blueprint('home_data', __name__)

@app.route('/')
def home():

    search = False
    q = request.args.get('q')
    if q:
        search = True

    page = request.args.get(get_page_parameter(), type=int, default=1)
    pagination = Pagination(page=page, total=users.count(), search=search, record_name='home_data')
    return render_template('home.html', home_data=Article.query.all(), pagination=pagination,)
```

And the HTML, though I suppose it hasn't even gotten that far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Home</title>
</head>

<body>

{{ pagination.info }}
{{ pagination.links }}

{% for dict_item in home_data|reverse %}

<!--<a href="results/{{ dict_item['id'] }}">-->

    <div class="photo">
        <img src="{{ dict_item['image_url'] }}" width="100%">
    </div>
    <div class="hometitlesstyle">{{ dict_item['title'] }}</div>
    <div class="voteorresult"><a href="votefor/{{ dict_item['id'] }}">Vote</a></div>
    <div class="resultbox"><a href="results/{{ dict_item['id'] }}">Results</a></div>

<hr class="new1">
    {% endfor %}

{{ pagination.links }}

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1:** Then, you must not have installed `Flask Paginate`. You can install the `Flask Paginate` using this:

```
pip install -U flask-paginate
```

**Option 2:** If you have installed Flask Paginate, then it must have imported in the wrong place. You can check it in your virtual environment using with this command:

```
pip freeze
```

You can see whether you have `flask-paginate` in that fetched list or not. If you have not installed the `flask-paginate` in your virtual environment, then you can activate your virtual environment and then install flask-paginate. For activating your virtual environment, you can use this command:

```
virtualenv venv
source venv/bin/activate
```

This will activate your virtual environment and then you can install your flask-paginate using this command:

```
pip install -U flask-paginate
```

Comment: When I try pip freeze, I do indeed see "flask-paginate==0.5.5" ... Hmmm, so I don't know why I'm getting the error. Is there another option? Am I referring to it incorrectly in my python file somehow?

Comment: Oh! I think I figured it out. I have to run python3, rather than python.

Comment: Ok. Great. Good to know. Glad I can help you somehow.